# Anime about gems that can give you powers

Tags: story-identification, anime

I’m looking for an anime. I think it was from the 80’s/90’s, not sure.

The things I remember was that there were multiple people who had gem stones that could give them power. Then there was a girl but they didn’t let her try any of the gems until one day she went shopping for rollerblades and found a gem that gave her the power of speed, if I’m not mistaken.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, can you describe the broad appearance of any of the main characters, such as age, sex, and hair length/colour?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Hi, thank you :) I think I watched it in 1999. I don’t really remember any of the characters, but I remember that they transformed with the stones they had and they were like a group? The leader seemed to be an adult male while the girl who found the stone in the roller blades was younger

Comment: Was this a movie or a series?

Comment: It was a series

Comment: Power Stone (1999)?